# Confused about this section on Brilliant.org, concerning area.

Tags: geometry

[image]

It says that if we divide the square into fourths horizontally, and thirds vertically. The triangle fits perfectly.

But the image shown is thirds (horizontally) and fourths (vertically)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Guess it means that you divide into fourths by drawing *horizontal* lines.

Comment: Related question from English.SE: [Split horizontally or vertically – which one is which?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/293520)

Comment: I thought about rotating the square and displaying it as to what the text says. Would that be a valid option?

Comment: Thank you, @Brian. This is a great visualizer.